# Magento change order address before save

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to write an observer in magento to change shipping address if shipping method is flatrate.

My problem is that i can't get shipping address from session and save my values.
Below I'm presenting my code

class Mydons_Eventdemo_Model_Observer {

```
    public function sales_order_save_before($observer)
    { 
      $order = $observer->getOrder();

        $shipping_address = $order->getShippingAddress();
        $shipping_method = $order->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();


         if($shipping_method == 'flatrate_flatrate') {
          $shipping_address
          ->setStreet(('Street 45'))
          ->setCity('MyCity')
           ->setPostcode(('91-000'));
         }
//how to save shipping address record in this event ? 

    } 

}
```

Can somebody please tell me how to get and change shipping address in this  observer method (I need to check shipping method)

Thanks for help
Best Regards

UPDATE:
Thanks to Chris Rogers I've updated my code

Update2:
Code from below is working like a charm ;)

```
<?php

class Mydons_Eventdemo_Model_Observer {

    public function sales_order_save_before($observer)
    { 
      $order = $observer->getOrder();

        $shipping_address = $order->getShippingAddress();
        $shipping_method = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();


         if($shipping_method == 'flatrate_flatrate') {
          $shipping_address
          ->setStreet('test street')
          ->setCity('Test City')
          ->setPostcode('91100');
         }
         $shipping_address->save();

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **getOrder** from the observer:

```
$order = $observer->getOrder();
$shipping_address = $order->getShippingAddress();
$shipping_method = $shipping_address->getShippingMethod();
if($shipping_method == 'flatrate_flatrate') {
      $shipping_address
      ->setStreet('test street')
      ->setCity('Test City')
      ->setPostcode('91100');
}
$order->save();
```

You also need to save on the order, not the address.

Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Now I have $shipping address  but I don't know how to save address in sales_order_save_before event

Comment: I have question , My script works on my developer localhost server (Xampp + Apache) but when I put module to production server observer is stopped by redirect event from payment method, When i put ;die; after scirpt i see that observer worked but payment method is still not updated.

Comment: PHP version different on live?

Comment: I can see in 'sales_flat_order_address' table that address is properly edited by observer. But in 'sales_flat_quote_address' table i see that adres is not edited by observer. Maybe I have save shipping address to quote too ?

Comment: Try passing by reference. So change line 2 to this: **$shipping_address = &$order->getShippingAddress();**

Comment: $order->save() in this observer should reault in infinite loop, since it's beforeSave observer. Am i right?

Comment: Great question, I've not tested this in a while but I haven't had this problem before.